# MongoHub mongo database GUI for Mac no longer works

Tags: macos, mongodb, mongohub

MongoHub installed on Mac OS X 10.6.8
program is having multiple problems (query, edit, add, delete) with database management.
anyone else experienced problems with MongoHub?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The original MongoHub 2.3.0 is no longer maintained** and will crash on current versions of OS X.

The [Fotonauts MongoHub fork](https://github.com/fotonauts/MongoHub-Mac) (currently 2.7) that's [mentioned on the official MongoDB site](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Admin+UIs) works as expected.

You can [download Fotonaut's MongoHub](https://mongohub.s3.amazonaws.com/MongoHub.zip).

Answer (score 2):

If you use Eclipse, then you can try the MONJA who is an excellent plugin

Comment: agree monja if far better than MongoHub on Mac

Comment: Representation of documents is better in monja, but it feels clunky and is seriously lacking in some functionality (count records, adjust limit and skip in find, managing connections (whats with this double login stuff)). I use both and am waiting for the ultimate solution.

Comment: @RickyA are you still waiting?

Answer (score 2):

Found [robomongo](http://robomongo.org/). Absolute the best up until now. Has osx, linux and windows versions.

Comment: I experienced problems connecting to localhost with MongoHub. `robomongo` connected straight up great and was very intuitive to use to view/delete collections